# Reading a file block wise in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-read

I am stuck in reading a file block wise where I have multiple conditions to work with and I am facing difficulty in getting some selected data in each block of file

File content:

```
Container:container_12345
=============================
LogType:container
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found:
java.io.Exception:Not initated
    at.apache.java.org........
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
```

I want to check for the ERROR/WARN messages in the `Log Contents:` of the `Logtype:stderr` in each container.

I want the output to be stored in dict in a list if I find any of ERROR/WARN messages in Log Contents

Eg:

```
  [{id:container_12345,
    Type:stderr,
    Upload_Time:Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020,
    Length:3000,
    Contents:{ERROR Exception found:java.io.Exception:Not initated, 
    WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started}
    }]
```

Here you can see in the ERROR message that it also needs take the second line of the particular message but not more than that.
Eg:

```
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found:
    java.io.Exception:Not initated
        at.apache.java.org........
```

While parsing the ERROR message I need to take the second line of the error message also such that in the dict I get`'ERROR Exception found:java.io.Exception:Not initated'` like this not the additional line.

I am stuck currently at the beginning of the program and below is my code

```
from itertools import groupby
import re
f=open("lg.txt","r")
grps=groupby(f,key=lambda x:x.strip().startswith("Container"))
for line in f:
    if line.starts.with("Container:"):
```

Also I thought of using another groupby function for `LogType:stderr` but that will result in more number of groupby functions since I need to check again for `LogContents`.

I also thought of using regex but I am not sure how to use that according to the above mentioned conditions.

Meanwhile I am also trying to come with the solution and will update if I find any. Please help me to solve.Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can create a YAML file using you text file data and read it using python yaml. load()

Comment: Yes but I was told to try without YAML file and only by reading the file block wise

Comment: split the data in the file then you can extract the data you want

Comment: You dont do that - using groupby for the line that starts with container will put all lines that do so in one group and all others in the other group. Read the file linewise and build the lists yourself. Throw away what you do now, won't get you there. Have fun - doubt anybody will write this code for ya.

Comment: The very first thing to do here is to explain where that log file is coming from, and whether you control its output format. Because if you do, force it into outputting structured data of _whatever_ type, and then use a preexisting Python library for parsing that type of data. Don't implement yourself what others have already done for you. And even if you don't: see if there is already a package out there for parsing the log output that you have right now, because you're almost certainly not the first person to have to parse logs from whatever tooling generated this.

Comment: I just need to do analysis of the log file to check ERROR/WARN messages in it. So I thought of taking the ERROR/WARN data first and store in a dictionary then I can easily  iterate through them for further analysis.

Comment: Parsing to yaml is as hard as parsing to a dict... I don't see how that helps. groupby works here (in fact a second groupby internal to the first may work). Just remember that groupby's returned iterator iterates the orginal file until the next time the condition is met. So,  `for line in grp:` gets you started.

Comment: Yes I thought of doing like that . Sure I will try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is primitive method - I get full text and use `split()` to separate parts.

First I use `split('Container:container_')` to split container.

Next in every container I use `split('LogType')` to separate `strerr`, `stdout`, etc.

Next in every `stderr` I use `Split('Log')` to separate `LogType`, `Log Upload`, `LogLenght`, `Log Contents`.

And finally in every `Log Contents` I use `split('20/')` to split every message to separate string. And this part would use `regex` because one in next year it would need `21/` instead of `20/`

Every message I split also on first three spaces to get separated data, time, message type and message text. See result at the end.

---

**BTW:**

I uses `json` only to display it. It gives nicer result then `pprint` (PrettyPrinter).

I was thinging about keeping also `stdout` and other `LogType`.

---

```
text = '''Container:container_12345
=============================
LogType:container
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found:
java.io.Exception:Not initated
    at.apache.java.org........
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:'''

#text = open(...).read()

all_containers = text.split('Container:container_')

results = []

for one_container in all_containers[1:]: # use [1:] to skip text before first `Container:`
    #print('\n--- Container ----\n')
    #print('Container:container_' + item)

    one_result = dict()
    #one_result['id'] = one_container[:one_container.find('\n')]
    one_result['id'] = one_container.split('\n', 1)[0]


    all_types = one_container.split('LogType:')
    for one_type in all_types[1:]: # use [1:] to skip text before first `LogType:`
        #print('\n--- LogType ----\n')
        #print('LogType:' + one_type)

        if one_type.startswith('stderr'):
            for one_log in one_type.split('Log')[1:]:
                #print('LOG>', one_log.strip())
                key, val = one_log.split(':', 1)
                key = key.strip()
                val = val.strip()
                if key == 'Contents':
                    messages = ['20/'+x for x in val.split('20/')[1:]]
                    one_result[key] = []
                    for msg in messages:
                        parts = msg.split(' ', 3)
                        if parts[2] in ("ERROR", "WARN"):
                            one_result[key].append({
                                'date': parts[0],
                                'time': parts[1],
                                'type': parts[2],
                                'text': parts[3].strip(),
                            })
                elif key == 'Length':
                    one_result[key] = int(val)
                else:
                    one_result[key] = val
            
    results.append(one_result)

import json
print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))

#import pprint
#pprint.pprint(results)
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "Upload Time": "Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020",
    "Length": 3000,
    "Contents": [
      {
        "date": "20/06/25",
        "time": "12:19:39",
        "type": "ERROR",
        "text": "Exception found:\njava.io.Exception:Not initated\n    at.apache.java.org........"
      },
      {
        "date": "20/06/25",
        "time": "12:20:41",
        "type": "WARN",
        "text": "Warning as the node is accessed without started"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "e182_1234",
    "Upload Time": "Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020",
    "Length": 3000,
    "Contents": []
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which use `re.split()` and `^` to match items only at the beginning of line.

I also use

```
re.split('^(?=\d+/)', val, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

to split on any date. And I use `(?=...)` (`lookahead`) to keep this value in date.

```
text = '''Container:container_12345
=============================
LogType:container
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found: Log
java.io.Exception:Not initated
    at.apache.java.org........
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR 
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:'''

import re

# text = open(...).read()

results = []

all_containers = re.split('^Container:container_', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(all_containers)

for one_container in all_containers[1:]: # use [1:] to skip text before first `Container:`
    #print('\n--- Container ----\n')
    #print('Container:container_' + item)

    one_result = dict()
    #one_result['id'] = one_container[:one_container.find('\n')]
    one_result['id'] = one_container.split('\n', 1)[0]

    #all_types = one_container.split('LogType:')
    all_types = re.split('^LogType:', one_container, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    for one_type in all_types[1:]: # use [1:] to skip text before first `LogType:`
        
        #print('\n--- LogType ----\n')
        #print('LogType:' + one_type)

        if one_type.startswith('stderr'):
            
            #all_logs = one_type.split('Log')
            all_logs = re.split('^Log', one_type, flags=re.MULTILINE)
            for one_log in all_logs[1:]:

                key, val = one_log.split(':', 1)
                key = key.strip()
                val = val.strip()
                
                if key == 'Contents':
                    
                    # create list for all messages
                    #one_result[key] = []
                    one_result['Contents'] = []
                    
                    # split on `20/` (and keep `20/` using `lookahead` `(?=...)`)
                    messages = re.split('^(?=\d+/)', val, flags=re.MULTILINE)
                    messages = messages[1:]
                    
                    # split on `20/`
                    #messages = val.split('20/')
                    # add back `20/`
                    #messages = ['20/'+x for x in messages]

                    #print('>>>', '>>> '.join(messages))
                    
                    # work with every message separatelly 
                    for msg in messages:
                        # split message on date, time, type, message
                        parts = msg.split(' ', 3)
                        
                        # filter by `type`
                        if parts[2] in ("ERROR", "WARN"):
                            
                            # add to list as dictionary
                            one_result['Contents'].append({
                                'date': parts[0],
                                'time': parts[1],
                                'type': parts[2],
                                'text': parts[3].strip(),
                            })
                            
                elif key == 'Length':
                    one_result[key] = int(val)
                else:
                    one_result[key] = val
            
    results.append(one_result)

import json
print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))

#import pprint
#pprint.pprint(results)
```

---

**EDIT:** Code splited to functions to make it more readable. I also added `line_start`, `line_end`.

It can parse all data and gives you python data which you can use later to search information. Or you can use arguments `filter_log_types` and `filter_content_types` to get only selected information.

```
text = '''Container:container_12345
=============================
LogType:container
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found: Log
java.io.Exception:Not initated
    at.apache.java.org........
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR 
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
'''

import re

def parse_file(text, filter_log_types=None, filter_content_types=None):
    """
    filter_log_types - it has to be list or tuple
    filter_content_types - it has to be list or tuple
    """
    
    full_text_lines = text.split('\n') # to get line number in `parse_log_contents`

    results = []
    
    all_containers = re.split('^Container:container_', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    #print('\n--- container ---\n'.join(all_containers))

    for item in all_containers[1:]: # use [1:] to skip text before first `Container:`
        data = parse_container(item, full_text_lines, filter_log_types, filter_content_types)               
        results.append(data)

    return results

def parse_container(text, full_text_lines, filter_log_types=None, filter_content_types=None):

    results = {}
        
    first, rest  = text.split('\n', 1)
    results['id'] = first

    all_log_types = re.split('^(?=LogType:)', rest, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    #print('\n--- logtype ---\n'.join(all_log_types))

    for item in all_log_types[1:]: # use [1:] to skip text before first `LogType:`
        
        data = parse_log(item, full_text_lines, filter_content_types)
        log_type = data['type']
        
        if not filter_log_types or (log_type in filter_log_types):
            results[log_type] = data

    return results
        
def parse_log(text, full_text_lines, filter_content_types=None):

    results = {}
    
    all_log_items = re.split('^Log', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    #print('\n--- all_log_item ---\n'.join(all_log_items))

    for item in all_log_items[1:]:

        key, val = item.split(':', 1)
        key = key.strip().lower()
        val = val.strip()
        
        if key == 'contents':
            results[key] = parse_log_contents(val, full_text_lines, filter_content_types)
        elif key == 'length':
            results[key] = int(val)
        else:
            results[key] = val

    return results
    
def parse_log_contents(text, full_text_lines, filter_content_types=None):
    # create list for all messages
    results = []
    
    # split on `20/` (and keep `20/` using `lookahead` `(?=...)`)
    messages = re.split('^(?=\d+/)', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    messages = messages[1:]
    
    # work with every message separatelly 
    for msg in messages:
        # split message on date, time, type, message
        parts = msg.split(' ', 3)
        
        if len(parts) < 3:
            print('WARNING: Not enough parts in message (needs 3 but get {}): {}'.format(len(parts), msg))
        else:
            msg_date = parts[0]
            msg_time = parts[1]
            msg_type = parts[2]
            msg_text = parts[3].strip()
            
            msg_lines = msg.split('\n')
            first_line = msg_lines[0]
            
            msg_line_start = full_text_lines.index(first_line)
            msg_line_end   = msg_line_start + len(msg_lines) - 1
            
            if not filter_content_types or (msg_type in filter_content_types):
                results.append({
                    'date': msg_date,
                    'time': msg_time,
                    'type': msg_type,
                    'text': msg_text,
                    'line_start': msg_line_start,
                    'line_end': msg_line_end,
                })

    return results

# --- main ---- 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # text = open(...).read()

    # parse_file(text, filter_log_types=None, filter_content_types=None):
    
    #results = parse_file(text)
    results = parse_file(text, ['stderr'], ['ERROR', 'WARN'])

    import json
    print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))

    #import pprint
    #pprint.pprint(results)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217858/discussion-on-answer-by-furas-reading-a-file-block-wise-in-python).